# xcodeを起動する事が出来るmacOSのバージョン一覧が欲しい

Tags: xcode, macos

Mac OSを12.1に更新したら、xcodeの12.5.1が起動しなくなってしまいました。
公式的には「Xcode 12.5.1は MacOS 11以降が必要」という表記しか書いてありません。
[Xcode 12.5.1 requires a Mac running macOS Big Sur 11 or later.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-12_5_1-release-notes#:%7E:text=Xcode%2012.5.1%20requires%20a%20Mac%20running%20macOS%20Big%20Sur%2011%20or%20later.)
特定のMacOSで、いつまでの古いxcodeが起動するか？を事前に調べる方法を教えて下さい。

現状自分が把握している手段の1つをシェアしますと、以下のxcodeのビルド時間のベンチマーク結果のサイトがあります。
https://github.com/devMEremenko/XcodeBenchmark
このサイト上ではXcode 12.5をMac OS 12.0.1でテストした記録が1件あるので、Mac OS 12.0は起動出来たが、12.1から弾かれるようになった？と推測出来ますが
本来の使い方ではないのでデータ件数が少なく、他の方法を探している状態です。

Answer (score 0):

Xcode のリリースノートから確認することができるかと思います。

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes

例えば 12.5.1 の場合は以下の通り。

[Xcode 12.5.1 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-12_5_1-release-notes)

> Xcode 12.5.1 requires a Mac running macOS Big Sur 11 or later.

Comment: xcodeのリリースノートでは「Xcode 12.5.1は MacOS 11以降が必要」という情報は読み取れますが、 MacOS 12.1では起動できない という情報はありません。その情報を知りたいです